# バッチファイルから起動したときだけ 502 Bad Gateway エラーが出る

Tags: vscode, virtualbox, vagrant, batch-file

### 問題の要約

Laravel の環境構築を vagrant と virtual box を用いて行いました．

ブラウザで画面のプレビューをするために毎回 git bash を起動して vagrant up していたのですが，これを自動化しようと思って バッチファイルを書きました．

こんな感じのバッチファイルです．gitbash から一行ずつ打ち込んで実行する時と一緒のはずです．

```bash
cd %USERPROFILE%/hoge/homestead
vagrant up
start http://preview.php
```

ところが，これを VSCode のターミナルから実行してみたところ 502 Bad Gateway エラーになってしまいました，

このエラー自体は vagrant destroy から再起動してデータベースと mysqlアカウントを復旧すれば元に戻すことができますが，しかし腑に落ちません．

なぜ git bash から一行ずつ打ち込んで実行した時と，vscode から「アクティブファイルを実行」で実行した時で結果が変わってしまうのでしょうか？

Comment: vscodeのターミナルでバッチの中身を一行ずつ打ち込むとどうなるか確認されてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: vscodeのターミナル(GitBashに設定)で一行ずつ実行すると問題なく動きました

Comment: バッチファイルの保存場所が問題かもしれませんね。[Shift] + [Ctrl] + [P]キーを押した後、「ターミナル」と入力して出てくる一覧から「ターミナル：アクティブなファイルをアクティブなターミナルで実行」を選んで実行したらどうなるでしょうか。

Comment: 「アクティブファイルをアクティブなターミナルで実行」した場合は502 Bad Gatewayエラーになります

Comment: 関係ないかもしれませんがバッチファイルの文字コードと改行コードはどうなっていますか？私の古い記憶だと文字コードがShift-JIS、改行がCRLFでないとうまく動かない場合があったと思います(最近のターミナルでは問題ないかもしれません)。

Comment: 文字コードはUTF-8にしていて，日本語が文字化けして困っていました．改行コードについては確認していなかったのでわからないです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

問題がどのような条件で発生するのか正確に述べることができていないので，この投稿はいったん解決済みとします．